# Change Color of .navigationTitle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is there anyway to change the .navigationTitle color? I tried .foregroundColor and even passing the Text as a view but that did not work.

```
 var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
           
            
            Divider()
            Spacer()
                .navigationTitle(myList.name)
            
        }.padding()
    }
```

I also tried using the UINavigationBar appearance:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes =  [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

Comment: It is important at which moment it is applied - it should be *before* creating `NavigationView`. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263541/12299030 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64304302/12299030.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change and update color of Navigation Bar in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262266/dynamically-change-and-update-color-of-navigation-bar-in-swiftui)

Comment: @Asperi So basically, I have a List view and depending on the item I clicked from the list, a different color text will be applied to the detail view .navigationTitle.

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of is simply ignore the navigation bar and recreate it myself by using the Text view.